# Magento 2 adding a custom link in a new column to product_listing.xml

Tags: magento2, module, backend, product-grid

*Trying to add a new column with a link into magento 2 **product_listing.xml** that passes entity id to a custom module.*

I have created the Ui Component `[company]/[module]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/EditActions.php` (see below), however I do not know how to add it to the layout. `[company]/[module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

See screenshot for an rough mock up https://prnt.sc/os44w1

```
<?php
namespace [company]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class EditActions extends Column {

    /** @var UrlBuilder */
    protected $actionUrlBuilder;

    /** @var UrlInterface */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_viewUrl = '[router]/content/view';

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $editUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {

                    $item[$name]['contentassist'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->_viewUrl, ['id' => $item['entity_id'], 'store_id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('link')
                    ];

                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to create custom product attribute for link

Comment: Do you need custom link in action or as column value?

Comment: Just a custom link that I can pass the entity_id. Trying to get it into another column so it can be user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, module name here is `Rendyep_CustomModule`, change it accordingly.

Create `app/code/Rendyep/CustomModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns">
        <column name="custom_link" class="Rendyep\CustomModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomLink" sortOrder="130">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <label translate="true">Custom Link</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Create `app/code/Rendyep/CustomModule/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CustomLink.php`

```
<?php

namespace Rendyep\CustomModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class CustomLink extends Column
{
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item['custom_link'] = '<a href="https://google.com/search?q=' . $item['entity_id'] . '">Custom Link</a>';
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Flush cache by executing `bin/magento cache:flush`

Result:

[image: Custom grid column with link]